# How to convert categories of variables into column and row headings in R

Tags: r

I have data as below:

```
    Stage Month
1       4   Jun
2       1   Jun
3       3   Jun
4       4   Jun
5       4   Jun
6       3   Jun
7       2   Jun
8       4   Jun
9       5   Jun
10      5   Jun
11      4   Jul
12      3   Jul
13      1   Jul
14      2   Jul
15      5   Jul
16      3   Jul
17      3   Jul
18      2   Jul
```

and I need to change it around so categories of stage become column headings and occurrences of each stage are summed for each month like this:

```
      1  2  3  4  5
Jun   1  1  2  4  2
Jul   1  2  3  1  1
```

I've tried everything I know like aggregate() etc. but I've hit my R limit. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `table(df)` should be enough.

Comment: I'm guessing your table is stored as a data frame, so this is a data table solution that works:
`library(data.table)`
`myData <- data.frame(Stage = c(4,1,3,4,4,3,2,4,5,5,4,3,1,2,5,3,3,2), Month = c(rep("Jun", 10), rep("Jul", 8)))`
`setDT(myData)`

`myData <- dcast(myData, Month ~ Stage, value.var = "Stage", fun.aggregate = length)`

`myData <- myData[order(match(Month, month.abb))]`